# Conditional probability of three-site linear chain (Markov process)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

A three-state system is described as follows with the letters being the transition probability between the 3 states [image]

([Source](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Non-Equilibrium_Statistical_Mechanics_(Cao)/01%3A_Stochastic_Processes_and_Brownian_Motion/1.01%3A_Markov_Processes))

I don't understand why $P(1,s+2|1,s) = q^{2}$. I expected $P(1,s+2|1,s) = \frac{P(1,s)*P(2,s+1|1,s)*P(1,s+2|2,s+1)}{P(1,s)}=\frac{q*p*q}{q}=qp$

Comment: What is the meaning of $P[1, s+2|1,s]$?

Comment: If $X_t$ is the state of the DTMC at time $t \in \{0, 1, 2, …\}$ then $P[X_{t+2}=1|X_t=3]=q^2$ and  $P[X_{t+2}=1|X_t=1]=pq + (1-p)^2$.

Comment: @Michael I think $P$ is the condtional probability distribution for a state at a specific time